# java save file stack trace

Tags: java, exception, file-io

I have a small issue with a method that should save the text contained in a JTextArea. When i call the method from default constructor thats not a problem at all and works. if i call the method from an an action listener with a JFileChooser i am getting the following exception (the file is getting generated but also the exception is getting thrown):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at text_editor.Editor.saveFile(Editor.java:186)
at text_editor.Editor.access$0(Editor.java:179)
at text_editor.Editor$SaveActionListener.actionPerformed(Editor.java:155)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:389)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:809)
at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuItemUI.doClick(AquaMenuItemUI.java:137)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:850)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6373)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6138)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4735)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4621)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:679)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:652)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:650)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:649)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

this is my save method:

```
private void saveFile(String path) throws IOException, BadLocationException{
    BufferedWriter buffer = null;
    try {   
        buffer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(path)));
        String lines[] = textfield.getText().split("\\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < this.textfield.getLineCount(); i++) {
            buffer.write(lines[i] + System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (buffer != null) {
                buffer.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "File saved","Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

this the JFielChooser Action Listener:

```
private class SaveActionListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {

            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(frame);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                    saveFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {

            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not save ArrayList to the FileSystem");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not save the selected file","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: don't know the reason, but possibly just doing a .replaceAll("\\n",System.getProperty("line.separator")) could be used, so one wouldn't need to use error-prone for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException so I suppose it is thrown when you call `lines[i]`:

`for (int i = 0; i < this.textfield.getLineCount(); i++)`

Should probably be:

`for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)`

Comment: damn it. what a stupid mistake. thanks for your help...i was now looking since an hour but did not find a solution for it. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that splitting by newline split("\n") returns a different count then getTextLines() on your TextArea.
Then later you use a for loop like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ______this.textfield.getLineCount()  ______; i++) {
            buffer.write(lines[i] + System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
        }
```

replace that this.textfield.getLineCount() with your String[] lines  .length field
like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      buffer.write(lines[i] + System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
}
```